# How to store network folder location within asp .net page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working a webpage where we store locations of where files are. Example would be

> H:/Sales/Projects

. I need to store these locations and users can click on the hyperlink to open file explorer of that selected location.

Currently I'm using `<input type="file" id="myFile" name="myFile" />` to import folder location which adds file which isnt needed or wanted.

I'm using hyperlink field within gridview to view.

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="outputItem" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="\\fs1.company.local\{0}" DataTextField="outputItem" HeaderText="Output Location" SortExpression="outputItem">
```

Answer (score 1):

because sites in IIS run under restricted credentials you would need to setup some new credentials that will have permissions to the network share. setup the credentials to have access to the network share on the share's host computer then setup the sites application pool to run under the same credentials.

Comment: Everyone has access to shared folders.

Comment: Are you on a domain? Do you have the guest account enabled on the server with the network share? Unless you have the guest account enabled then the everyone just refers to all users on the server with the share. The IIS default user account on the IIS box won't have a matching account on that server with the share.

Comment: I will try this